# How do I remove my 'Title' from my Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story

Apologies for the number of screenshots below. I have removed my **title** from my Developer Story a long time ago which used to display my old Job Title. This field is now blank:

[image]

However, whenever I view my profile, it's still there. How do I get rid of this? (I assume that's what this line is showing - I could be wrong).

#### Developer Story Tab

[image]

#### Main Profile tab

[image]

I have added other job titles since this one yet it still shows. Also to note, I can only see this on my profile when I'm logged in - I do not see it in incognito mode (my profile shows as being set to public).

**In repsone to Nilesh Rathod's answer, this field is already blank:**

[image]

**Update: If I change my title to anything, it updates...**
[image]

However, setting it back to blank, I end up with my old title again...
[image]

Comment: See the duplicate, go to *[Edit Profile and Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) - Career - Current position*. Here, *Career* is a section further down on the page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, that worked! I did look for duplicates but couldn't find anything. The functionality here seems counter-productive. It ended up _very_ confusing to figure out where it was coming from as the title in developer story seems to show instead of that field on profile if it is set.

Comment: The profusion of titles is a little bewildering, yes.